# IQ test: a Letter sequence

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

I'm looking for solution & plausible explanantion which letter comes next in following riddle:

[image]

Source (german): https://www.matheboard.de/thread.php?threadid=1459

Update: The correct answer is B. Does anybody know a plausible argument?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: the correct answer is B but still don't know how to derive it. I updated the question

Comment: Two answers below put forward answers for B, one with 7 upvotes at this moment - I suggest you look further into those :)

Answer (score 9):

> The answer is B

The secret is Fibonacci series. The edges that connect the letter nodes are either blob ended or flat ended.

> We only care about the flat ended edge on each node. So, 'J' has 1 flat ended edge, similarly 'I' has 1 flat ended edge.

The node 'H' has 2 concentric circles around it.

> So, we multiply the number of flat ended edges of 'H' by 2 which gives us 2. The node 'G' has 3 flat ended edges. The node 'K' has 5 flat ended edges. The node 'F' has 4 flat ended edges with 2 concentric circles around the node. So, we have 4 times 2, which is 8. The node 'A' has 13 flat ended edges.

If we write the sequence out we have 1,1,2,3,5,8,13. The next one should satisfy 21.

> The node that satisfies 21 is 'B'. This is because node 'B' has 3 concentric circles around it and 7 flat ended edges. If we multiply them we get 21. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

> My answer is E

**Theory:**

**pointer on J**

> j, I, K = there is a single line both sides. line between k and j is
>  having a circle in the end toward j side and between j and I, there is
>  a circle at the pointer end, and I side both.
>
>  so the next letter came up is I. it means away circle is having higher
>  priority.

**Pointer on I**

> I, D, H, J = there are all 3 single lines and away circle is only j side
>  that means and next letter coming is not j that means the letter will
>  not repeat. now between H and D, it moves towards H because there is a
>  circle between d & I towards pointer side on line and there is no
>  circle between I and H.
>  
>  that means no circle letter have high priority than the line where
>  circle is cursor end. also, letter will not repeat

**Pointer on letter H**

> now we already knew that no letter will repeat and priority of line is
>  like 
>  
>  away circle line > no circle line > pointer circle line
>  
>  now there is both the line C & G pointing towards H that means the
>  priority is equal but the letter came up in series next is G.
>  
>  that means the letter comes after in alphabetical order is having
>  higher priority.

**Pointer on letter G**

the pointer moves towards K,

> it is clear with a line theory that priority is equal but K comes
>  after B in alphabetical order so pointer moves towards K.

**Pointer on letter K**

> now j and G are both repeated letters we already figure it out that
>  repeated letters will not come up in series again.
>  
>  so pointer moves towards F

**Now pointer moves towards A because**

> if the number of lines is more it has more priority.
>  
>  Now, finally E will come because the number of a line between E & B is same
>  no circle at all. so priority is equal so we will go according to
>  alphabetical order E comes after B in alphabetical order. So answer is
>  E

**Rules wise Theory**

> 1) no alphabet will repeat. (first check)
>  
>  2) the more the number of lines the higher the priority.( second
>  check)
>  
>  3) the line with circle away from the pointer is having the highest
>  priority, as compared to the line with no circle is higher than the
>  line where circle is toward pointer end. (3rd check)
>  
>  4) if line priorities are equal we go with alphabet order priority.
>  the letter comes later in alphabetical order is having higher
>  priority. (4th check)

Comment: But by this logic it could also be B, C or D... Why choose this letter over any of those?

Comment: @Stiv yes, I later find out that my previous logic was wrong... but this one is 100% correct.

Comment: You set of rules does apply to the known sequence, but there are so many variables to choose form that many different sets of rules will work. I have no clue what the answer is, but I expect the rule to be much simpler

Comment: @MKBakker if you try you may come up with different rules but I am sure you will need more than one rule to solve this answer. and it is totally depend on the number of lines, type of lines and alphabets. I gave explanation how I able to find out those rules and after that I explained what are 4 rules you need to apply to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @MKBakker I have other theory maybe you can find out... as you can see in outer circle the letters are in sequence  G,H,I,J,K and also in inner circle BCDEF, I think it is just to confuse people instead of lines and alphabetical order... but maybe any intelligent brain can still make theory on it.

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> B. Because this is the only option that allows the path to be a Hamiltonian cycle.